# Update query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, changestream

Suppose I have this document in mongodb collection:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "playerId": "113069",
    "tournamentId": "197831"
  },
  "__v": 0,
  "playerName": "David WArner",
  "pointsTotal": 426
}
```

I update it using this update query(using mongoose):

```
await PointsTotal.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        _id: {
          playerId: player._id,
          tournamentId: tournamentId,
        }
      },
      {
        $set: {
          playerName: playerName,
          pointsTotal: totalPoints
        },
      },
      {
        upsert: true,
      }
    );
  }
```

But, if the playerName and totalPoints is same as before updating, will it perform update operation to overwrite these fields and I am able to listen this update in change stream or not?

Answer (score 1):

No, if there is no change to the document MongoDB will not perform a write, there will be no operation in the oplog, and nothing will appear in the change stream.